# create workspace into perforce server

Tags: perforce

I am trying to create workspace into perforce so it will be available to other person who would like to add or submit file. I was following link which suggest to create new workspace

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4v-gs/01_p4v-gs.html#1060773

I got one question, why perforce is looking into my local directory which can be deleted at any time.

Comment: Your other developer should create her own workspace, on her own laptop. Each developer creates their own workspace(s); they don't have to be created by the central administrator. The workspace local directory is where each developer assembles their pending changelist with adds, deletes, and updates to the versioned files.

Comment: @BryanPendleton that is a very confusing comment.  please leave an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Judging by our response to gmaghera there is confusion over what you are tyring to achieve.

Comment: @TobyAllen here's a longer answer, which overlaps a fair amount with gmaghera's answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36404691/193453

Answer (score 1):

The local directory that you mention is the root of the workspace.  That's how Perforce knows where to put files when you tell it to get files from it.

You have a couple of options.  One is to create a workspace and put /dev/null (or some other non-existent directory) and ask the eventual owner to change it before using the workspace.  They should also change ownership to themselves.  It is important that you don't "lock" the workspace when you create it, otherwise they won't be able to modify it, take ownership, or even use it.

Another option would be for you to create a workspace (for yourself), and then ask the other user to create a workspace, using yours as a template.  The command line way is p4 client -t  .  Doing this via P4V, you would ask the user to find your workspace from the workspaces view, right click, and then  from the contextual menu choose "Create/update Client using Clientname as Template..." (the wording might be slightly different, I don't have P4V open right now).

I recommend you go with option two.  Doing so will automatically set ownership to the correct user, and the user will also be prompted to choose a local directory for the workspace root.

Comment: Thanks but I am talking about some centralized workspace like /depot/test which can map by developed into p4 client  //depot/test  //bruse/test

Comment: @user765443 //depot/test... is not a "centralized workspace". It is a set of files under version control on the server. Workspaces are specific to each user. If you want to put some files into the server, you run 'p4 add' followed by 'p4 submit' to add them, using your workspace, and your colleague uses 'p4 sync' to retrieve the new versions of the files into their workspace.

Comment: p4 add for submit file. when developer run p4 client we generally map to workspace with perforce in following //depot/library .../library which say in depot we have library which will be copied into user workspace. I would like to create //depot/library am I able to convey message

Comment: I recommend you create a workspace for yourself, and try to use it, before trying to create one for others.  It will help you understand how it works.